# Shell script to add a full stop at the end of each line (that do not contain a full stop) in a file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have a file with each line a sentence e.g.

```
Random stuff,
"First sentence",
"second sentence.",
"Third sentence!"
More Random Stuff,
```

and so on...

I want to in-place modify only the quoted lines i.e. 2nd, 3rd and 4th line in the example above.

I want to do the following modifications -

1. Add a full stop at the end of line (if a full stop or exclamation mark is not present)
2. Make first character capital (if its not already capital)

I have tried the following solution to add a full stop -

```
sed -i 's/[^!.]",/.",/g' $file
```

The above command removes the last character of the sentence as -

```
"First sentenc.",
```

And if I try the following command -

```
sed -i 's/[^!.]",/&.",/g' $file
```

I get result as follows -

```
"First sentence",.",
```

My desired output is -

```
"First sentence.",
```

How can this problem be solved correctly without getting undesired results as shown above?
Also, how can I make the first character capital?

The file after modification should be -

```
Random stuff,
"First sentence.",
"Second sentence.",
"Third sentence!"
More Random Stuff,
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, I have added my desired output. I forgot to add it initially.

Comment: Like `sed 's/^"[[:lower:]]/\u&/;s/\([^.!]\)",/\1.",/' file`??

Comment: @oguzismail I think minor correction is needed: sed 's/^"[[:lower:]]/\U&\E/;s/\([^.!]\)",/\1.",/' file. The matched region is include leading quote. Need to uppercase both quote and the 's'.

Comment: @dash-o I didn't understand a word

Comment: Hi @oguzismail, I tried your solution, it correctly solves the fullstop problem but does not make the first character uppercase.

Comment: @HarshVardhanMall Oh yeah, `\u` is wrong, it needs to be `\U`, I guess that's what dash-o was trying to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^".*",/{s/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/;s/([^!?.])",$/\1.",/}' file
```

Focus only on quoted lines. Uppercase the first alphabetic character and insert a period before the closing quote if it is not an exclamation/question mark or period.